# Firebase Auth in Cross-Origin-Isolated mode?

Tags: firebase, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

I am working on a web app, which runs compute-intensive code using Emscripten's multithreaded WASM and therefore needs SharedArrayBuffers. Those only work if my app is in Cross-Origin-Isolated mode. And to enable that, I have to set the following headers on my app:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

Now, I would like to use Firebase in my project - first step is to integrate Firebase's Auth. Right now, I'm using `firebaseui` for handling the login flow. Unfortunately, that doesn't work and when I'm starting the login flow in my browser, I can see the following message in DevTools:

[image: DevTools Error]

[image]

Apart from the error in the network tab, I don't get any indication that an error happened (i.e. no uncaught exceptions). Without the COOP/COEP headers, everything works fine.

Is there a way that I can use Firebase's Auth in Cross-Origin-Isolated mode?

Comment: ...I just found this page, which mentions this as a known issue and indicates that it is being worked on: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer

As I see it right now, I'm concerned that I wouldn't be able to use Firebase at all in my scenario.